# How to impersonate another Windows login in an ADODB connection?

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic

How do I via an ADODB.Connection object connect to a MS SQL Server using a specified set of Windows credentials?

Example:

```
Dim oConn  
Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim oRs
Set oRs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Dim strConnection
Dim strSQL
strSQL = "SELECT * from Computer WHERE DeviceName = N'myDevice'"

oConn.Provider = "SQLOLEDB.1"
oConn.Properties("User ID") = "myDomain\myUser" 
oConn.Properties("Password") = "myPassword" 
oConn.Properties("Initial Catalog") = "myDB"
oConn.Properties("Data Source") = "mySQLServer"
oConn.Open
```

If I do like that, then it fails with the error below:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e4d' 

Login failed for user 'myDomain\myUser'.
```

Checking the SQL Server log shows this error:

```
Login failed for user 'myDomain\myUser'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <IP>]
```

The account "myDomain\myUser" has access to the SQL Server as it's a member of a group that has "sysadmin" privileges on the server. I can RDP to the SQL Server using the same username and successfully open Management Studio and manage the SQL Server.

What I essentially would like to achieve is to use integrated security as I'm running this via a web page on IIS where you have to authenticate using Active Directory to get access. The authentication part is working, and `Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")` will show the correct username.

If I replace the "User ID" and "Password" part with `oConn.Properties("Integrated Security") = "SSPI"` then I get the error below:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e4d' 

Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
```

Which isn't my supplied credentials?

How can I make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things worth noting.  If you're trying to login with a windows domain account, then you're probably trying to use a Trusted Connection.  You'll need to configure IIS to not allow Anonymous Access and turn on Integrated Windows authentication (this might be different depending on which version of IIS you have installed and which OS).

Look at the following connection strings and see if they don't help (these might be different depending on which db you are using -- just google for the appropriate):

To use the logged in users credentials

```
strConn = "Driver={SQLServer};Server=your_server_name;Database=your_database_name;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
Set cnt = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnt.ConnectionString= strConn
```

To use a SQL Server username and password (not domain name and password)

```
strConn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=mySQLServer;Database=myDB;uid=someUser;pwd=somePass"
Set cnt = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnt.ConnectionString= strConn
```

Good luck.

Comment: IIS is configured to not allow anonymous access and Integrated Windows authentication is enabled, and I'm being prompted for credentials when opening the page. Using your connection string still gives me the `"Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'` error

Comment: Are you able to create a SQL Server user and then use those credentials?  This is how I generally connect to DBs.  I use integrated authentication when I need to capture user information from my code.  Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I don't know why I couldn't get it working on Win2k3 / IIS6 but what you suggested is working fine on Win2k8R2 / IIS7.5. Thanks.