# vbscript - SQL Windows Authentication - different user

Tags: sql-server, windows, authentication, vbscript

I want to read data from an SQL Database in my VBS Script.
My problem: I need to logon with Windows Authentication and **not with an SQL Account.** But I cannot use

```
ConnectionString ="Driver={SQL Server};Server=myLocalServer; Database=myDb;trusted_connection=yes;"
```

because I do not want to use my Windows Account to logon. I do not have the permission.
I need to open the connection with a different Windows User.

How can I do that? Using **UID** and **PWD** is only for SQL Accounts as far as I know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to impersonate another Windows login in an ADODB connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584031/how-to-impersonate-another-windows-login-in-an-adodb-connection)

Comment: Unfortunately not because I see no solution for using another Windows Account in this quest

Comment: Login as the other windows user and use a trusted connection.

Comment: That is not possible. The script is executed by users who do not have and are not allowed to have the credentials for the user I need to access the SQL database. This has to happen automatically.

Comment: @user18209625 "Unfortunately not because I see no solution" - Exactly, there is your answer.

Comment: Log on/run the script with the Windows account that you want to use for your connection. There is no substitute for that, that's how Windows authentication works. Otherwise put the users that are supposed to run the script into an AD group, and grant the proper database permissions to that AD group on your SQL server. Then people in that group will be able to run the script under their own accounts. Those are you two options. Personally, I would prefer the latter.

Answer (score 0):

ADODB should work.

```vb
Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection : Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim objRs As ADODB.Recordset : Set objRs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

objConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
                           "Data Source=servername.contoso.com;" & _
                           "Initial Catalog=database;" & _
                           "User ID=username@contoso.com;" & _
                           "Password=lmaocleartextpassword;"

objConn.Open

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Database.dbo.Table Where BlahBlah"

Set objRS.ActiveConnection = objConn
objRs.Open strSQL

' Do stuff with objRs data

objConn.Close
Set objRs = Nothing
Set objConn = Nothing
```